# Kafka topic consuming in android

Tags: android, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Is it possible to consume a Kafka topic on Android?

I have a scenario: I have a microservice implemented based on Spring Boot, and I am trying to publish a message in a Kafka topic.

Now the challenge is whether it is possible to consume the same topic in an Android application. Yes, it is feasible. Please give me some references.

Otherwise, what is the best way to send a message asynchronously from my microservice to an Android application?

I can implement a producer and consumer in a Spring Boot application because I know the APIs that are provided by the Spring framework.

I would like to know the approach and how I can implement it in the same manner in android application.

Any help would be really appreciated.